C++ How can I declare a local variable in a function without continuously updating it?
New to C++ but not entirely to programming. I am stuck on this one problem. This function is called within a loop that has constantly updating 'c' values. I want to keep the scope of the storedVal var within the call but don't want to initialize it each time. How can I declare it properly?
void fun(float a[], float c){

    float storedVal = (0.0f); //"on" is a global bool
    if (on) {
        storedVal = c;
        on = false;
    }
    else if (c-storedVal > 0.5) {
        a[0] = storedVal;
    }
}

in this example each time on = true, I want it to update storedVal. But isn't this just iterating through storedVal = 0?

"on" is a global bool be careful with this one. Global variables have a tendency to be very friendly while writing, but make you regret them later while debugging.

The on == true case does nothing but sets on = false. The on == false case storeVal plays no role it basically clears a[0] based on c. As to the intent of your code, it's unclear.

static float storedVal = (0.0f); may be the answer you are looking for. A static variable is initialized once and holds its value between multiple calls (it has static storage duration). Note that this means the code doesn't suffer fools well when multithreading.

A function's non-static local variables have a lifetime of the invocation of the function, so they must be initialed each invocation of the function. DO you mean that you want the variable to persist between invocations of the function? Besides a global, 3 ways to do that, each with its own characteristics/issues: 1) make it a static local; 2) make it a member function of an object and make the variable a member variable; and 3) move ownership of the variable to the caller and pass a pointer to it to the function.

Side note: do you realize that void fun(float a[], float c)  is passing a pointer to the first element of an array whose size is unknown and undeterminable to fun()? (unless it is terminated with a sentry value) If you use more than the first element, consider passing a reference to a std::vector instead.

And if you only use the first element, consider passing in a reference to just that one element.

@user4581301 I have multiple calls passing different arrays to this function. This is why I need storedVal to stay generic for each call. My intention is to update it once when on = true and then use it as a comparator to see when on = false. I will try what you suggested.

@AviBerger yes, I know that passing an array as an argument decays them to a pointer. Does it matter that the function doesn't know the size in this case? As I am not iterating through it

As a side note, C++ has invented classes many versions ago, which are generally much better than trying to use statics to keep state between function calls. Yes, you could solve the the thread-problem with threadlocal variables, but what if you want to start a new calculation? Do more complicated stuff?

That is a vital bit of information that needs to be in the question. Different stored values for different calls says you want @AviBerger 's second option: wrap the function in a class, define the stored value as a member, and have a different instance of the class for every case. It's possible that those might be static.

As long you are not going past its end, no, it doesn't matter to functionality. @user4581301's suggestion might make the usage intent clearer to a reader/future maintainer.

Each time on == true, you want to update storedVal. But what if on == false? Should storedVal == 0.0f?
